# How is the runner used to run the Callable in FutureTask<V>

Tags: java, futuretask

In the [source code of `FutureTask<V>`](https://github.com/ZenOfAutumn/jdk8/blob/master/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.java), there is a `volatile` *instance variable* `Thread runner`, where the comment told that it is the thread running the callable. However, the `runner` is never initialized in the source code. Moreover, I could not find any clue how this `runner` is used to run the callable.

**Question: Since the `runner` is never initialized, how it is used to run the `Callable`?**

Comment: In the source listing you link to there's some calls to `sun.misc.Unsafe` with the `runner` field.  I assume the field is initialized by native code. `UNSAFE.objectFieldOffset(k.getDeclaredField("runner"));`

Comment: @markspace, I think you mean places like `UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject(this, runnerOffset, null, Thread.currentThread()))`. `objectFieldOffset` just returns field offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you can see

```
if (state != NEW ||
        !UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject(this, runnerOffset,
                                     null, Thread.currentThread()))
```

at the start of the `run` method.  Ignoring the `state != NEW` part; this attempts to set the `runner` variable to the result of `Thread.currentThread()` (and will succeed only if it is currently `null`).  Only if this succeeds (returns `true`) will the `run` method be able to go through the rest of the code in this block.  And since the result of `Thread.currentThread()` will be the `Thread` which called the `run` method, the documentation is accurate (at least, after this initial `if` part is successfully evaluated).

Comment: Thanks a lot :) In addition to this, I feel that the FutureTask is like a proxy to the Callable (subject), isn't it?

Comment: @Rui  , yes, to some extent.  The _result_ of the `FutureTask` is obtained by invoking the `Callable`; however there is additional functionality added (reporting, only being callable _once_, etc.) which is not provided by the simple `Callable` item.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this is only a single implementation of `FutureTask`.  Other JDK implementations may choose to _not_ delegate to a `Callable` (although I suspect pretty much all sane ones would).